# creating/ guessing the underlying models from JSON response

Tags: django, django-models

I am building an application and it was easier for me to think of the JSON response I will get when hitting a specific URL and then based on that now I am trying to build my models.

JSON looks like following:

```
{ 
  "idea": { 
    "title": "", 
    "description": "", 
    "tags": [ 
      "", 
      "", 
      "" 
    ], 
    "priority": "", 
    "PD": [
        { 
          "question": "what's your name?", 
          "answer": "" 
        },
        { 
          "question": "what's your address?", 
          "answer": "" 
        },
      ], 
    "TOC": [
        { 
          "question": "Age?", 
          "answer": "" 
        }, 
        { 
          "question": "Gender?", 
          "answer": "" 
        }, 
    "issues": [ 
      "issue1", 
      "issue2" 
    ], 
    "tasks": [ 
      "task1", 
      "task2" 
    ], 
    "note": "", 
    "image": [ 
      "base64(1)", 
      "base64(2)" 
    ] 
  } 
}
```

I started creating models like following (this is more or less Django syntax for models, but I guess logic remains the same for any framework):

```
class Tag():
    name = string;
    idea = ForeignKey(Idea);

class Prototype():
    base64 = string;
    idea = ForeignKey(Idea);

class Issue():
    name = string;
    idea = ForeignKey(Idea);
    task = ManyToMany(Task);

class Task():
    name = string;
    idea = ForeignKey(Idea);

class Idea():
    title = string;
    description = string;
    priority = string;
    note = string;
```

I am not sure about the PD, TOC and HOW parts. Could they be attributes of Idea or could they be separate models and in that case what could be the relationship between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They could be either:

You could just keep them as json with a JSON field

or they could be a `OneToOne` relationship via a `OneToOneField`

```
class Idea():
    pd = OneToOneField(Question)
    toc = OneToOneField(Question)

class Question():
    question = 'foo'
    other_question = 'bar'
```

Comment: JSONfield looks amazing, I didn't know about that. Thanks!